# How to deactivate dhtmlx tab,when click on the second time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX tabs, in my case, initially my tab is in `InActive` state. When user clicked initially the tab comes to `Active` and loading the content using `setContentHref()`.

Again if I click on the same tab for second time I don't want to display the content and the tab comes to initial state.

For this I have implemented like

```
tabbar.attachEvent("onTabClick", function (id, prevId) {
                    alert(id); alert(prevId);
                    if (id == prevId) {
                       tabbar.setTabInActive(id);
                       return true;
                    }
                });
```

but the tab does not come into the `InActive` state. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTabClick occurs before a tab is selected and setTabInActive doesn't block selection. Therefore, you need to set onSelect handler, for example like so:

```
var disabledTab;
tabbar.attachEvent("onTabClick", function (id, prevId) {
    if (id == prevId) {
       tabbar.setTabInActive(id);
       disabledTab = id;
    }
});
tabbar.attachEvent("onSelect", function (id, prevId) {
    if (id == disabledTab) {
        return false;
    }
    disabledTab = null;
    return true
});
```